# Map modelA to modelB in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have two unassociated models which normally would be associated. This is however sort of a freak-case where I don't want them to be associated.

In the view, I can do this:

```
<%= @user.each do |user| %>
   <%= Option.where(:id => user.option_1).or(Option.where(:id => user.option_2).each do |option| %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

How can I move that logic to the controller?

If I, in controller do

```
@user = User.all.map do |user|
   @options = Option.where(:id => user.option_1).or(Option.where(:id => user.option_2)
end
```

The results of `@options` do not map to the `@user` object the same way it would `@user.options` if models were associated.

Is there a way to mimic that functionality when the models are not associated so that when I loop through `<% @users.each do %>` I can access `<% @options.each do %>` within that scope the same way I would if `:options` belonged to `:user` and `:user` had many `:options`

So that the final output in the view would look like this:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <% @options.each do |option| %>
      #Outputs the result of Option.where(:id => user.option_1).......
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You don't have much code here so it's hard to see what you really want. Can you show the actual data structure you hope to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to loop `options`, you should do this

In controller

```
@options = Option.joins("INNER JOIN users ON users.option_1 = options.id OR users.option_2 = options.id").distinct
```

In view,

```
<% @options.each do |option| %>
<% end %>
```

Give it a try.

Comment: No I want to be able to loop both the same way I would @user.options.each do if user has_many :options and belongs_to :user.